# How can I send [SYN] with bare sockets?

Tags: sockets, ftp, tcp, vxworks

I'm writing a bare bone ftp client just using sockets on **VxWorks** and I now would like to receive directory contents.
For that I need to send a `Request: LIST` and following a `[SYN]` which initiates the data transfer back to me but I'm wondering how I do this with simple sockets?
My code to send the `LIST` just looks like this:

```
char lst[6] = "LIST";
lst[4] = 0x0d; // add empty characters on back
lst[5] = 0x0a;
if (write (sFd, (char *) &lst, 6) == ERROR) 
        { 
        perror ("write"); 
        close (sFd); 
        return ERROR; 
        }

if (read (sFd, replyBuf, REPLY_MSG_SIZE) < 0)  { 
        perror ("read"); 
        close (sFd); 
        return ERROR; 
    }

printf ("MESSAGE FROM SERVER:\n%s\n", replyBuf);
```

but it actually gets stuck in the read() until it times out as the server doesn't respond unless i send a 'SYNC` to initiate the connection.

**edit**

Upon suggestion, I replaced the addtion of 0x0d and 0x0a at the end of my string with **\r\n** directly top the string which changed my code to:

```
char lst[6] = "LIST\r\n";
if (write (sFd, (char *) &lst, strlen(lst)) == ERROR) 
        { 
        perror ("write"); 
        close (sFd); 
        return ERROR; 
        }

if (read (sFd, replyBuf, REPLY_MSG_SIZE) < 0)  { 
        perror ("read"); 
        close (sFd); 
        return ERROR; 
    }

printf ("MESSAGE FROM SERVER:\n%s\n", replyBuf);
```

but I get exactly the same result, my client does not send a `SYNC` message - why not I am wondering...?

Comment: It's quite unclear what you mean by [SYN], that would normally mean a TCP syn, which you do not send yourself, you leave it to the TCP/IP stack - which the connect() call would do for you. Remember to login to the FTP server first though.

Comment: @nos yes, I mean a TCP syn and yes, I did login to my server but all manually by first connecting to my server then sending `USER:` and `PASS:` information followed by a `PASV` and an `LST` from which I wanted to receive the return but i don't see an automatic `[SYN]` on Wireshark at all...

Comment: If you use passive FTP, you need to set up a new socket, connect that to the port indicated back to you with the PASV command. The result of the LIST command will be given back to you on that new socket, not on the command socket you send the "LIST" command on. What is the significance of logging in "all manually" ?

Comment: @nos, ah really? Okay, would you recommend to use `PASV` mode or the "normal" `PORT` mode? Saying this, I have not been able to get the correct arguments for PORT yet...I know, it's a combination of port and ip... but the port is always 21, is it not?

Comment: passive mode is normally nicer with nat gateways and the like. If you're not using passive mode, you need to open a listening socket, the server will connect another tcp connection back to you on that socket and send the result of LIST there.

Comment: @nos So I either way have to open a second connection... good to know... Thanks!

Comment: @nos Okay, seems Thanks to your tip, I got that going now! You can add this as an answer and I'll accept it if you want to...

Answer (score 0):

> For that I need to send a Request: LIST and following a [SYN] which initiates the data transfer back to me

No you don't. The [SYN] is sent automatically when you connect a TCP socket.

> char lst[6] = "LIST";

The problem is here. It should be

```
char[] lst = "LIST\r\n";
```

All FTP commands are terminated by a line terminator, which is defined as `\r\n`.

Comment: but I'm adding `0x0d` and `0x0a` behind list